# Show calendar on desktop via a widget?

Tags: desktop-environment, calendar

I'm using Linux Mint 17.1 + MATE running Thunderbird v31.7 + Lightning for my mail/calendaring app.

I'd like to have some kind of desktop widget to show my calendar, but screenlets doesn't seem to have any good options and general web searches have too low a signal to noise ratio for me to zero in on a solution.

Can anyone recommend a good way calendar desktop widget that will sync with Lightning, or with both Exchange and Google calendars?